# Function that takes string as Input, evaluate it like a calculator and return the Integer answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to Implement a function that takes in a string input such as "1+2-3" or "-2+2", evaluate it like a calculator and return the integer answer.

In the example, it would return 0 for both inputs. We can assume that there will only be + or - operator (no multiple/division/or any other operator), as well as input is well formed so we don't need to do any validation (i.e. it's always alternating operator/operand).

I need it with out using existing Python functions like calc() etc. Instead I tried developing a simple code that does this actually.

My code is

```
d =  {}
sum = 0
for index, value in enumerate(s):
   if value.isdigit():
           pass
   else:
           if not value.isdigit():
                   d[index] = int(s[index]+s[index+1])


for i in d.values():
   sum += i
```

But it's working only for the case of "-2+2".

How could I make this to work for the case of "1+2-3" also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea in your code, but are trying to effectively add to the `sum` by referencing the next `character` in the `string` which limits you to a `string` of form:

```
.a.b
```

where `.` is a `+` or `-`.

What you want to do is iterate through each `character` in the `string` and if that `character` is a `plus` or `minus` (i.e. not a `digit`) then change the multiplication variable to a `1` or `-1` respectively. Then, whenever you reach an actual digit to add or subtract, you just add that digit times by the multiplication value.

So here is the code for the logic outlined above:

```
s = "1+2-3"
m = 1
sm = 0
for c in s:
    is c.isdigit():
        sm += m * int(c)
    else:
         m = -1 if c == "-" else 1
```

which outputs `sm` as:

```
0
```

---

*Bare in mind that this only works when the `string` alternates between an `operation` and a `digit`.*

Comment: @Rajan Please accept then! That is how the site works **:)**

Comment: I am new here. Could you please guide me how to accept the answer?

Comment: @Rajan There is a little grey tick to the left of my answer which goes green when you press it to indicate that this answer solved your problem

Comment: @Rajan Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

pythonic way is to use `eval`

```
eval("-2+2")
eval("1+2-3")
```

If you want to implement with your way then

```
def f(s):
   s = s.replace('-', ' -')
   s = s.replace('+', ' +')
   l = s.split(" ")
   sum = 0
   for num in l:
       sum = sum + float(num)
   return sum
s = "4747-74+484-44"
print (f(s))
# output: 5113.0
```

Comment: The OP wants a custom way to calculate the result, not use any existing Python functions

Comment: @ThePretendProgrammer that's not the proper way to use the python code. That is the worst way of coding in python. we should simplify the code and should not make it complex.

Comment: I am not exactly praising the OP's coding style, simply pointing out that he requested the calculation logic be written by-hand. We can simplify the code while writing the calculation logic ourselves :).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But, I need it with out using existing Python functions

Comment: Thanks @AnjaneyuluBatta

Comment: I tried to upvote. But it's saying - Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded , but do not change the publicly displayed score.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy using regular expressions. `re.finditer(r'([+-]?\d)', d)` will find all occurrences of single digit numbers which may be optionally preceded by a sign. Add a `+` after `[+-]?\d` and you can calculate multi digit numbers too.

```
import re

d = '-2+2'    
total = sum(int(i.group()) for i in re.finditer(r'([+-]?\d+)', d))
```

Comment: Tried. Getting TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only catering for addition and subtraction, the below solution should work for any of your above mentioned examples:

```
def calculate(s):
   sWithAdd = s.replace('-', '+-')
   numbers = sWithAdd.split('+')
   return sum([int(i) for i in numbers if i != ''])

t = '1+2-32+64-71'
print(calculate(t)) #Prints -36, the correct answer
```

The above code works in the following steps:

1. First, for all the `-` (minuses) in the string, we replace them with `+-`. The resulting string for our example becomes, `1+2+-32+64+-71`. The reason we do this, is to convert our input into a series of addition of numbers
2. We then split the string on `+`, giving us just numbers that are simply meant to be added.
3. Finally, we sum all the numbers of the list using the `sum` function in python. You can use a custom for-loop for that purpose if required.

Comment: Thanks @ThePretendProgrammer